# Disable Report Execution in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I inherited an old instance of SSRS 2008R2 dating back 6 years or more.  There are a lot of reports that are old and likely not used.  I have the executionlog tracking for a few months so I started looking at cleaning up reports that are not used.  However subreports and the base report (for a linked report) do not show up in executionlog. I can find out which reports have linked reports but not which ones are subreports. What I am thinking is, if I disable a report (not hide it, actually prevent its execution) I can begin to clean up the server. If I find out there is an error I can just enable the report. Is there a way to disable execution? (Disable from manual or subscription) There is a field [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog].[ExecutionFlag] but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Other then deleting the report and deploying it again, is there a way to disable a report execution?

Of course if I could track subreport execution that would be great too. Feel free to toss out any other ideas on cleaning up an old reporting server as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are these reports subscription based and you are trying to clean up these subscriptions so that they are no longer being sent out to an e-mail/file share? If so, simply deleting the subscription would achieve the desired result. Reports won't execute unless called on by a user, a third party program, or subscription.

Comment: They are a combination of manual and subscription.  However I run into the same problem with subscriptions as I do with the executionlog.  A report will not show a subscription if it is only called as a subreport.  This is why I would like to disable rather then delete, I have no way of knowing if/when a report is ever run. If I knew that, it would solve my problem, hence looking for a way to just disable.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into doing this at a security level. Unless you're specifying a domain group in Site Settings > Security, you could ideally remove the accounts that you want to restrict from running reports. You could also perhaps remove the Data Source reference entirely - this option is more granular. I've not been introduced to a method to "disable" running a report besides subscriptions. It's usually just saved off and removed entirely.

Comment: OK.  I will look at security as an option.  Might go with deleting even though that is not my preference.

Answer (score 0):

I would find The Visual Studio solution(s) with the source code for these reports. If they can't be found, you can recreate them by downloading the rdl files and adding them to project(s).

Then you can use Visual Studio's Find in Files to easily search for subreport references.

There would be many other good reasons to do this for maintaining or searching for other things across the reports.